# Livewire v3 Unable to find component: [forms.setting-form]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I need another pair of eyes seeing where I'm going wrong trying to load my setting form component in my Livewire project.

My form is located under:

- class: App\Livewire\Forms\SettingForm.php
- view: resources\views\livewire\forms\setting-form.blade.php

My CreateSetting class is located under

- class: App\Livewire\Pages\Settings\SettingCreate.php
- view: resources\views\livewire\pages\settings\setting-create.blade.php

the create page tries to load the form:

```html
<livewire:forms.setting-form />
```

and I get an error:

> Unable to find component: [forms.setting-form]

What am I missing?

Comment: Please provide render methods from both components.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try ?

```
<livewire:forms.SettingForm />
```

In my case, i am calling the components on Pascal Case, referencing directly the Class name.

Check if the class name of the component, it's also on Pascal Case.